# Accessing EBP using MOV in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

Why does the following instruction not work

```
MOV esi,ebp-4
```

while this does

```
MOV esi,ebp
```

Answer (score 3):

Because that's how the instruction set has been designed. Consult the instruction set reference. As an alternative, you can do `lea esi, [ebp-4]`.